# SQL query - Find the names of those ingredients of which we used a total of 4 or more teaspoons across all recipes in the database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've been stuck on this for a while.

**Find the names of those ingredients of which we used a total of 4 or more teaspoons across all recipes in the database.**

[At  all  times, underlined means  that  this  attribute  or  these  attributes are  the  primary key for the table. An attribute in italic and bold refers to an attribute that is a foreign key pointing to another table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjreY.png)

I've been trying things along the lines of...

```
SELECT name
FROM ingredient
JOIN recipe_ingredient ON ingredient.id = recipe_ingredient.ingredient_id
JOIN measurement ON recipe_ingredient.measurement_id = measurement.id
WHERE description = "teaspoon"
AND amount >4;
```

But I'm not entirely sure if I'm getting the correct result. I'm getting a list of ingredients but who knows.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Results looking like -

NAME
Salt
Black Pepper
Salt
Nutmeg
Cinnamon
Lime Juice 
Black Pepper

etc etc... I know i can add distinct to remove the doubles

Heres a sample of my table when i enter

```
SELECT *
FROM ingredient
JOIN recipe_ingredient ON ingredient.id = recipe_ingredient.ingredient_id
JOIN measurement ON recipe_ingredient.measurement_id = measurement.id
```

[Table Exert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U62Pl.png)

Comment: `4 or more teaspoons` - might want to change `> 4` to `>= 4`.

Comment: post create table statement along with some sample values, also describe the output

Comment: Thanks! You think it looks good though?

Comment: @rocks I'm not too sure how to do that, just a beginner.

Comment: Can you give us a table example, i think you're missing a group by. Maybe i'm wrong i want to be sure. Simply edit your post and describe your table like this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96125/how-to-format-sql-tables-in-a-stack-overflow-post

Comment: across all recipes I understand as a sum in all recipies. Your query give names that are used at least 4 teaspoons in each recipe

Comment: My recipe for apple pie uses 17 teaspoons of sugar so would you expect to see sugar in the result or does 4+ teaspoons of sugar  have to be used in every recipe in the database? Also, I had to convert some tablespoons of sugar into teaspoons in order to do the comparison: do you? Also, I've included the dough recipe in the 17 tally because it is a sub-component of the pie recipe: should I have counted it separately?

Comment: paste the output screenshot for the below queries
select * from ingredient; select * from recipe_ingredient ; select * from measurement ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that we're looking for ingredients that were used at least 4 teaspoons in all recipies, not the recipes that used 4 teaspoons

```
SELECT i.name
FROM ingredient i
JOIN recipe_ingredient ri ON i.id = ri.ingredient_id
JOIN measurement m ON ri.measurement_id = m.id
WHERE m.description = "teaspoon"
group by i.name
having sum(ri.amount) >= 4;
```

Comment: I understand you, but that query returns no results.

Comment: @JackMcAnulty can you please try now. There was a typo in query

Comment: One result, and that result is Salt!

Comment: @JackMcAnulty I don't see your data so it is hard to say if that's correct or not. I would also consider what are other measurements. Maybe you need to apply condition that spoon = 2*teaspoon or some other calculations. What measurements you have there? I was also missing >=

Comment: I don't think it was as advanced as spoon = 2*teaspoon so i doubt that would come into play!

Comment: Mate I think I've got it with the assistance of yours, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

If you give us an example of your table maybe i can be more precise on your query.

Like this gives you the name of that ingredients that are used 4 or more teaspoons

```
SELECT name
FROM ingredient
JOIN recipe_ingredient ON ingredient.id = recipe_ingredient.ingredient_id
JOIN measurement ON recipe_ingredient.measurement_id = measurement.id
WHERE description = "teaspoon"
AND amount >4
GROUP BY name, recipe_title; --Grouping by removes also repetitions not only distinct
```

Comment: Gave a table example there

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now the system I'm using is giving no results for my original query or any of your queries...LOL

Comment: I cannot say it, because it is an ingredient being used with 4 or more spoons (which is salt), or the single spoon must have an amount of >=4 (which none exists)?